# Difference between IE and IE.DomContainer

Tags: dom, watin

What's the difference between

```
IE.DomContainer.Button(Find.ByText("sometext")).Click();
```

and

```
IE.Button(Find.ByText("sometext")).Click();
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Button' is actually a virtual property of 'Document' which both IE and DomContainer inherit. So yes, this is the same thing (as stated by the previous answer). It might be worth it to look at the definitions of these classes, it might shed some light on how things relate.

Answer (score 1):

None - where else would you be looking for a button except for the DomContainer? The Button class uses the DomContainer and a finder to get a button.